# Scaling object moves it away from pivot point

Tags: modeling, objects, transforms

I've been following step by step the following tutorial: https://youtu.be/sgBbnF3r60U?t=201

As seen in the video he scales the plane from the pivot making the origin of the plane remain the same. For some reason that is not happening to me, I must be doing something wrong

After setting the pivot point to 3d cursor and scaling this is what happens:

Before scaling it:

[image: Before scaling it]

After scaling it:

[image: After Scaling]

Answer (score 2):

There is a gap between the origin and that right-most edge. Move the origin to the edge by...

Go to the Tool Settings and check Origins under Options > Transform > Affect only.

[image]

Turn on snapping by clicking the Snap button or with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Set it to Edge Center.

[image]

Select the object. Use <kbd>G</kbd> to Grab the Origin and hover over the edge to snap the origin to the edge.

Uncheck Affect Only Origins in the tool settings panel. Now you can scale the object and the edge will stay in place.

[image]

---

Another way of moving the origin is to go into Edit Mode. Select the edge. Snap the 3D cursor to the edge with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>2</kbd> OR Mesh >  Snap > Cursor to Selected. Exit Edit Mode into Object Mode, then right click > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor.